# Translation Service between front end and Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have the opportunity to design our application's advanced search. I have a good understanding of writing Elasticsearch queries and know how the front end and back end will interact, but what I can't seem to find a good solution for is how to make it "easy" for the front end to build a query and have the back end translate it and then execute that search. Are there libraries for these types of issues? If there is any good read material on this type of issue I'd appreciate anyone who can provide a link. The application is a MEAN stack application if that matters.

Comment: Why frontend should even be able to write anything? It should be endpoint with parameters such give me users with firstname equal to something

Comment: By the way have a look to https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/what-can-odata-bring-to-elasticsearch/